# Line break in TextView adds padding

Tags: java, android, textview, padding

This is my TextView:

```
public IconifiedTextView(Context context, IconifiedText aIconifiedText) {
    super(context);

    /*
     * First Icon and the Text to the right (horizontal), not above and
     * below (vertical)
     */
    this.setOrientation(HORIZONTAL);

    mIcon = new ImageView(context);
    mIcon.setImageDrawable(aIconifiedText.getIcon());
    // left, top, right, bottom
    mIcon.setPadding(0, 3, 7, 3); // 5px to the right

    /*
     * At first, add the Icon to ourself (! we are extending LinearLayout)
     */
    addView(mIcon, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    mText = new TextView(context);
    mText.setText(aIconifiedText.getText());
    mText.setTextSize(16);
    /* Now the text (after the icon) */
    addView(mText, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));


    mInfo = new TextView(context);
    mInfo.setText(aIconifiedText.getInfo());
    /* Now the Info (below the Text) */
    addView(mInfo, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
}
```

And when i call the object I have:

```
this.directoryEntries.add(new IconifiedText(currentFile
                    .getPath(), currentIcon, "\nInfo"));
```

Where "\nInfo" will be replaced by something later. When i run this, I get this:

```
d
 Info
data
    Info
dev
   Info
system
      Info
```

How do i get rid of this padding to the left of Info so they both start at the same place?

Answer (score 0):

```
this.directoryEntries.add(new IconifiedText(currentFile
                    .getPath(), currentIcon, "\r\nInfo"));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but no luck... its still indented.